# SmartGit pull not acting like expected

Tags: git, smartgit

I forked a repository on GitHub.

I then cloned my fork into a folder on my local development enviroment through SmartGit.
Additionally I added the original repository as a remote.

Now, the original repository has added and changed some files. I'd like to retrieve these so that I'm up to date, before continuing with developing.

I the push the Pull button in SmartGit and select the original repo i the dialog.
SmartGit returns this to me:

```
remote: Counting objects: 24, done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 7), reused 12 (delta 6)
From github.com:Original/repo
 * [new branch]      master     -> lm/master
```

But, the added files and changes are not added to my local repository.
Doing this manually with Git Bash - `git pull original master` everything works like expected.

Why is it SmartGit doesn't pull like I expect?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using SmartGit 3.0.x. When opening the Log and using Graph|Select Branch to show "All branches", can you see the other commits? What does Branch|Branch Manager show for Local Branch "master"?

Comment: @mstrap After pulling, the log does show the commits, but the changes aren't pulled.
The branch manager looks like this: http://postimage.org/image/qpp3mgu1x/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On **Pull**, SmartGit will perform a "git fetch" and after that merge resp. rebase the *tracked branch*. In your case, `master` tracks `origin/master`, not `lm/master`. You have following choices now, always assuming you are on `master`:

(1) Configure `master` to track `lm/master` instead of `origin/master`: invoke **Branch|Branch Manager**, select `master`, invoke **Reset Tracked Branch** from the context menu, then add `lm/master` to the selection and invoke **Set Tracked Branch**. Now, it's `lm/master` which will be merged (or rebased) on every **Pull**.

(2) Manually merge `lm/master`: invoke **Branch|Merge** and select `lm/master`.

(3) Manually rebase onto `lm/master`: invoke `Branch|Rebase`, select **HEAD to selected commits** and on the graph-page, select *lm/master*.

Comment: Looks quite SmartGit-detailed. +1

Answer (score 8):

What I ended up doing in SmartGit was:

- `Remote > Add` (as you did). I called mine **upstream**.
- In the branches panel `Right click upstream > fetch more..` and select the branches. (Typically master)
- In the branches panel `Double click upstream > master`. This will ask you to create a 2nd branch (usually master-2). I also called this **upstream**. So I have a remote repo called upstream and local branch called upstream that tracks upstream/master.
- In the branches panel `Double click Local Branches > Master` to get you back to your master branch.

At this point I would presume you only just forked the project a few moments ago, so this next step would not be very useful, but if there are a few extra commits at a later stage you will need to do this.

- `Remote > Pull` and select **upstream**. If you press the little down arrow, you will see you can **ONLY** do "Neither merge nor rebase". This is good.
- `Click fetch` This will allow you to see all the log and what has changed.
- In the branch panel `Right click Local Branches > upstream > Merge`.
- `Fast-Forward` if you believe you can. (My preferred way).
- or `Create Merge-Commit.`

From this point on, You would only have to do is the last 5 steps.
The first steps were just setup.

Answer (score 3):

You would see the new files if the **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)** of your current local branch was "`lm/master`".
But if you are on `master`, its upstream branch is certainly by default "`origin/master`" (ie the `master` of your fork)

If you want to merge the files from the original repo, complete your command with a

```
git merge lm/master
```

Or, [in SmartGit, merge](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation.html?page=merge) from `lm/master` to your current branch.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The problem is not pulling from the Git Bash, but pulling from SmartGit.

Comment: @Repox Sure, I have edited the answer, but basically what you want to do is a merge after your SmartGit pull. And SmartGit allows you to do that. My point was to explain why you had to do an extra operation (be it through your GUI or the bash) in order to see the files.

Answer (score 3):

if SmartGit is performing *Fetch* on your every *Pull*,

Then locate the branches option in menu bar or branches window from the application..
[image]

Then

[image]

OR

[image]

Voila... Enjoy